# Unterminated object at character 404372 unfindable

Tags: android, json, eclipse

I'm getting the error in Eclipse for my android app:
Unterminated object at character 404372 (!!), how can I find where the error is exactly.
When I use websites like JSONLint or http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ they all say the JSON is correct.

Comment: Where are you getting this error in Eclipse? It sounds like you copied the JSON string into an editor window inside Eclipse?

Comment: When I use LogCat on a running device. The application gets this JSON from a python server

Comment: Are you sure the JSON string is not truncated when you fetch it from the server?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure, too bad I can't post the JSON here, 'cause it's clients' information. It's a JSON of 1.1 MB. But that shouldn't be a problem aye?

Comment: What happens if you just print the JSON in a normal `System.out.println()` instead of `LogCat`?

Comment: can you paste a similar JSON format, which you are receiving. Change the key and values to some random values

Comment: It's a bug in the JSON parser of Android. It gets an &quot; which gets parsed to a double quote, and then the JSON is invalid.